# javascript image slider next previous

Tags: javascript

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide'); 
 var current = 0;
    var Interval = setInterval(next,2000);

   function next() {
    slides[current].className = 'slide'; 
    current = (current+1)%slides.length;
    slides[current].className = 'slide showing';
   }
```

```css
#slides {
    position: relative;
    height: 332px;
    width:100%;
    
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    
 
    max-height:332px;
 height:332px;
 overflow:hidden;
 width:100%;
    
   
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 40px;
color:#fff;

    
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;

 }

.showing {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul id="slides">
    <li class="slide showing"><img src="1.jpg"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="2.jpg"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="3.jpg"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="4.jpg"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="5.jpg"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="6.jpeg"></li>

 </ul>
```

Hi,I am new to javascript have done sliding i donno how to add next and previous button for the slider .anybody provide a function in javascript

I can't figure out what the problem is, maybe some one can help me.

Comment: Why not use https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html
- simpler
than reinvent the wheel.

Comment: i am a beginner i wanna learn the things and then i can go for plugins can anyone add the next and previous button in js @RahilLakhani